# Why is my operator overload not called for "<" when I use pointers?

Tags: c++, pointers, reference, operator-overloading

When I overload the `"=="` and `"!="` operators I am passing pointers as parameters and the overloaded functions are called and I get the results that I expect but in debugging I discovered that during my call `cout << (fruit1 < fruit);`, my overloaded `"<"` method is not being called. Why is the `"<"` operator the only one not being overloaded? I have passed a reference parameter instead to test it and de-referenced `fruit` and `fruit1` in the function call and it worked so the function itself works. Is it a property of those individual operators or the fact that the `"!="` and `"=="` methods are inline that is allowing them to work?

CPP

#include "Fruit.h"

```
using namespace std;
Fruit::Fruit(const Fruit &temp )
{
    name = temp.name;
    for(int i = 0; i < CODE_LEN - 1; i++)
    {
        code[i] = temp.code[i];
    }
}
bool  Fruit::operator<(const Fruit *tempFruit)
{
    int i = 0;
    while(name[i] != NULL && tempFruit->name[i] != NULL)  
    {
        if((int)name[i] < (int)tempFruit->name[i])
            return true;
        else if((int)name[i] > (int)tempFruit->name[i])
            return false;
        i++;
    }
    return false;
}
std::ostream & operator<<(std::ostream &os, const Fruit *printFruit)
{
    int i = 0;
    os << setiosflags(ios::left) << setw(MAX_NAME_LEN) << printFruit->name << " ";
    for(int i = 0; i < CODE_LEN; i++)
    {
        os << printFruit->code[i];
    }
    os << endl;
    return os;
}

std::istream & operator>>(std::istream &is, Fruit *readFruit)
{

    string tempString;
    is >> tempString;
    int size = tempString.length();
    readFruit->name = new char[tempString.length()];
    for(int i = 0; i <= (int)tempString.length(); i++)
    {
        readFruit->name[i] = tempString[i];
    }
    readFruit->name[(int)tempString.length()] = '\0';
    for(int i =0; i < CODE_LEN; i++)
    {
        is >> readFruit->code[i];
    }
    return is;
}
void main()
{
    Fruit *fruit = new Fruit();
    Fruit *fruit1 = new Fruit();
    cin >> fruit;
    cin >> fruit1;
    cout << (fruit == fruit1);
    cout << (fruit != fruit1);
    cout << (fruit1 < fruit);
    cout << "...";  
}
```

H

```
#ifndef _FRUIT_H
#define _FRUIT_H
#include <cstring>
#include <sstream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>
#include "LeakWatcher.h"
enum { CODE_LEN = 4 }; 
enum { MAX_NAME_LEN = 30 };
class Fruit
{
private:
    char *name;
    char code[CODE_LEN];
public:
    Fruit(const Fruit &temp);
    Fruit(){name = NULL;};
    bool operator<(const Fruit *other);
   friend std::ostream & operator<<(std::ostream &os, const Fruit *printFruit);
    bool operator==(const Fruit *other){return name == other->name;};
   bool operator!=(const Fruit *other){return name != other->name;};
    friend std::istream & operator>>(std::istream& is, Fruit *readFruit);
};

#endif
```

Comment: Why are you overloading your operators to take pointers instead of references?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your `operator<` is a member function, which means that it works for types `Fruit, const Fruit*`, and you try to pass it `Fruit*, Fruit*`.

When you declare an operator as a member function then the left parameter is implied to be `Fruit`. If you want something else, then you have to make a global operator. Unfortunately, you need a class or enumerated type as a parameter, so you can't have two pointers.

One way to get around this limitation. Instead of

```
cout << (fruit1 < fruit);
```

use

```
cout << (*fruit1 < fruit);
```

I also want you to know that this:

```
(fruit == fruit1)
```

compares the *pointers* not what they point to. In your case those are two distinct objects, so that pointer comparison will always return false.

Comment: *"then you have to make a global operator"* -- Except you can't.  When overloading an operator, at least one of the operands needs to be a user defined type.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley thanks for the correction, I wasn't aware of that limitation until now. But it makes sense, overloading a pointer comparison could lead to havoc.

Comment: So is there no way to do this comparison without de-referencing the objects first (without major headaches anyway)? And why do these rules not apply to the `"=="` overload? I mean, isn't it also a member function with types `Fruit, const Fruit*`?

Comment: @CraigPatrickLafferty `==` is a pointer comparison, not your overload. See my edit. You can write a regular function, for example called `less_than(const Fruit*, const Fruit*)` and use that instead.

Comment: I see. I didn't test it thoroughly enough and as it turns out I wasn't actually getting the correct results for the `"=="` or `"!="` operators. So none of them work.